# Can't paste text into CMS Pages!

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

Each time I try and paste something into a CMS Page i get an error. Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

The error reads:

> Currently not supported by your browser, use keyboard shortcuts
>   instead.

Comment: Which browser you used? Is there any custom extension which related to CMS module?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a Magento related question.

Answer (score 1):

Source from: https://www2.owens.edu/faq/entry/587/

Your web browser currently does not support your current behavior.

Use the following keyboard shortcuts instead:

```
Cut : Control + X (Command + X) 
Copy : Control + C (Command + C) 
Paste : Control + V (Command + V)
```

Many browsers no longer support the right click options for the content editor.

If you get this pop-up, use the keyboard shortcuts recommends instead.

For more information on keyboard shortcuts, please visit the following websites.

Windows Users:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449

Mac Users: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple keyboard shortcuts in that case:

- CTRL + **A** = Select All
- CTRL + **X** = Cut
- CTRL + **C** = Copy
- CTRL + **V** = Paste
- CTRL + **B** = **Bold** Text
- CTRL + **I** = *Italic* Text
- CTRL + **U** = Underline Text

Keyboard shortcuts can make your life easier when you become used to of these shortcuts.